# Travelling wave in a duct

Tags: waves

Is it possible to have a travelling wave in a duct? I understand that wave motion in a duct with reflections at the ends of the duct (open or closed boundary) creates a standing wave pattern. What boundary conditions would create a travelling wave in a duct? Or is it even possible?

Comment: I assume you mean in, e.g., air. If air is flowing through the duct, would you not describe that as a traveling wave?

Comment: This site might give you most of the answers?  https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/flutes.v.clarinets.html

Comment: @JonCuster: I am looking for a continuous wave pattern in a duct which is not a standing wave. In practical situation a simple duct has reflections at the end which always leads to a standing wave. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid any reflection at the extremities in your model, you can use [PML conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_matched_layer), these are commonly used for numerical simulation of transparent boundary conditions.

Note that traveling waves in a duct can happen even with reflections at the extremities. For example, a small impulse at some place of the duct will generate two traveling waves (one in each direction) which will go back and forth in the duct at each reflection at the extremities. The difference with a standing wave is that there may not be any nodes (points with no motion) except the extremities of the duct. In fact, this is quite a common situation when there are several modes involved, a standing wave being guarantied only for single modes.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider an air filled tube, you can have traveling sound waves in it. This was formerly used on ships for internal communication. When you excite a wave in the tube locally, you will have two traveling waves in the tube running towards the ends of the tube, where, in general, they will be reflected so that, e.g. for continuous harmonic excitation standing wave patterns will arise in the tube. If these reflections are eliminated at the end of the tube, e.g., by appropriate absorbers, you just have traveling waves in the tube.

Comment: If I have to eliminate reflection at the ends, what kind of boundary conditions I need? For a standing wave I know that the $p'=0$ and $u'=0$ for open and closed boundary respectively. What would be corresponding BCs for a travelling wave?

Comment: @Saravana Kumar - If you could find a termination with the characteristic acoustic impedance of the tube, this boundary condition would eliminate reflections at the ends completely. Also a perfect absorber would do it. These boundary conditions would be necessary for travelling waves only in the tube. Maybe you should ask an acoustics expert for practical implementations.

Comment: @Saravana Kumar You can use [PML conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_matched_layer), these are commonly used for numerical simulation of transparent boundary conditions.